# Pentaho 5.0.1 CE Error port 9001 already in use

Tags: port, hsqldb, pentaho

0.1 CE locally and it works fine. However on my remote server it fails to start because port 9001 used by hsql is already in use. I want to change the port 9001. How do I do this pls. I get that I may however eventually have to use mysql db instead of hsqldb but I want to try changing the port first for now. Help pls

Answer (score 1):

Fixed following: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?51100-HSQL-server-port-conflict

> In Pentaho 3.7.0 there is an undocumented context parameter to
>   configure which port Pentaho will use when starting HSQL. Add this to
>   web.xml and it will be read by the listener
>   org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.HsqldbStartupListener

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>hsqldb-port</param-name>
  <param-value>YOUR_PORT</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post - it's quite old, but still applies.
Are you sure however something else is using 9001?  quite rare, i wonder if you just have a previous instance of pentaho still running!

http://www.prashantraju.com/2010/12/pentaho-3-7-with-mysql-postgresql-oracle-and-sql-server/

Comment: Actually that was the issue. I had an older version still running. I wanted to keep running the older version and still test the new one on another port.

Comment: SonarQube uses the port 9001.